# number of way selection k vertices from n vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

let $c_n$ is a cycle with $n$ vertices.

i need the number of ways of selection $k$ vertices from $n$ vertices such that any two vertices are adjacent.

can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you need atleast one pair of adjacent points then fix it and consider pair as one point. Now select $r-1$points out of $n-1$ vertices. If you want all points adjacent then consider $r$ points as 1 .now select$1$ point out of $n-r+1$.